# Error when running Headless Chrome in Jenkins Docker using puppeteer

Tags: docker, jenkins, debian, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I run Jenkins in Docker(Debian9) to test Angular 7 app by using ChromeHeadless browser.
I've the following in karma.conf.js

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath()
 karmaConfig.customLaunchers = {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-gpu']
      }
    };
```

I've installed the following in my Docker:

```
RUN apt-get install -yq  libc6-i386 libXss1 gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

When running the tests in Jenkins I get the following:

```
 [39mChromeHeadless stderr: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/new-sample-
project/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-662092/chrome-linux/chrome:
 error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object
 file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what the problem is? Is it related to the installed packages in Debain? What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

the `libX11.so.6` library is provided by the `libx11-6` package.
so make sure you have that installed.